# AngularJS Infinite Scrolling with lots of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to create an infinite scrolling table using AngularJS, similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

The problem I'm having is that in the jsfiddle example, if I keep scrolling till I have a million results, the browser is going to slow to a crawl, wouldn't it? Because there would now be `1,000,000` results in $scope.items. It would be better if I only ever had, for example, `1000` results at a time inside $scope.items, and the results I was viewing happen to be within those `1000`.

Example use case: page loads and I see the first `10` results (out of `1,000,000`). Even though I only see `10`, the first `1000` results are actually loaded. I then scroll to the very bottom of the list to see the last `10` items. If I scroll back up to the top again, I would expect that the top `10` results will have to be loaded again from the server.

I have a project I did with ExtJS that a similar situation: an infinite scrolling list with several thousand results in it. The ExtJS way to handle this was to load the current page of results, then pre-load a couple of extra pages of results as well. At any one time though, there was only ever `10` pages of results stored locally.

So I guess my question is how would I go about implementing this in AngularJS? I kow I haven't provided much code, so I'm not expecting people to just give the coded answer, but at least some advice in which direction to go.

Comment: Why would the Angular implementation be that different form the ExtJS implementation?  In other words, what part of the ExtJS implementation are you having trouble porting to Angular?  It seems like you would still preload, and just adjust what is in $scope.items, rather than adjust what is in the DOM (which is what I'm guessing the ExtJS implementation does).  Instead of DOM manipulation, just do $scope manipulation and let Angular automatically update the view.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Now that you've said that does seem obvious :P However there is one thing I'm still not sure how to do. In ExtJS the scrollbar for the infinite scroll list gave the impression that all the data had loaded, i.e. I could move the scrollbar to the bottom and I would be looking at the very last item. How would you mimic this in AngularJS?

Comment: That would be difficult, since Angular is in control of displaying the view, and the current scrollbar size would undoubtedly be related to the current size of $scope.items.  You'd probably need to write your own directive to implement a custom scrollable container (if you really think this feature is needed).

Comment: Infinite scrolling in general is under scrutiny recently because of a lot of issues with: Usability, SEO, traffic flow, as well as DOM-related performance issues when you get to "1,000,000" rows. Perhaps it's time to rethink the implementation.

Comment: I think react.js can be used in such a scenario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So turns out that the [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/#/overview) module for AngularJS has pretty much exactly what I needed. If you look at the [examples page](http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/#/examples), the Server-Side Processing Example is also an infinite scrolling list that only loads the data that is needed.

Thanks to those who commented and answered anyway.

Latest URL : **[ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/)**

Comment: The examples page doesn't seem to match your original question. They are only rendering the DOM elements that are within the viewport but are not loading the data to match the viewport. They are loading the data using traditional paging.

Perhaps they have changed their example. Was it working as described in your initial question?

Comment: @RichardZschech No, subsequently I found out that the examples worked as you described. I didn't have any look searching for an alternative, so I've since changed the page's design.

Comment: this looks like the most robust, modular solution. ability to expand rows is definitely a nice plus. i do not see as many features with any other library. ng-vs-scroll looks like it has high performance, but also looks like its rotting on the git tree =/.

Answer (score 47):

A couple of things:

1. "Infinite scrolling" to "1,000,000" rows is likely to have issues regardless of the framework, just because you've created millions and millions of DOM nodes (presuming you have more than one element in each record)
2. The implementation you're looking at doing with `<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.foo}}</li>` or anything like that will have issues *very* quickly for one big reason: `{{item.foo}}}` or any ngBind like that will set up a `$watch` on that field, which creates a lot of overhead in the form of function references, etc.  So while 10,000 small objects in an "array" isn't going to be that bad... 10,000-20,000 additional function references for each of those 10,000 items will be.

What you'd want to do in this case would be create a directive that handles the adding and removing of DOM elements that are "too far" out of view as well as keeping the data up to date. That should mitigate most performance issues you might have.

... good infinite scrolling isn't simple, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: I agree completely with what you said. What I want to do is only actually load the couple of rows of data that are "in view". The bit I'm having trouble with is how to give the impression that these rows are part of a much bigger data set.

Comment: And i'm here searching for a dom unloader

Answer (score 26):

I like the angular-ui implementation ui-scroll...

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll

... over ngInfiniteScroll. The main difference with ui-scroll from a standard infinite scroll is that previous elements are removed when leaving the viewport.

From their readme...

> The common way to present to the user a list of data elements of undefined length is to start with a small portion at the top of the list - just enough to fill the space on the page. Additional rows are appended to the bottom of the list as the user scrolls down the list.
>
> **The problem with this approach is that even though rows at the top of the list become invisible as they scroll out of the view, they are still a part of the page and still consume resources**. As the user scrolls down the list grows and the web app slows down.
>
> This becomes a real problem if the html representing a row has event handlers and/or angular watchers attached. A web app of an average complexity can easily introduce 20 watchers per row. Which for a list of 100 rows gives you total of 2000 watchers and a sluggish app.

Additionally, ui-scroll is actively maintained.

Comment: vote for you though I hate switching from already working but poorly maintained infinitescroll

Answer (score 17):

It seems that http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat would be what you are looking for. It is a virtual scrolling directive.

Comment: This one is really awesome, but I am not lucky after reading their known limiations. +1

Answer (score 6):

You may try using ng-infinite-scroll :

http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Note that this is for Facebook-style truly-infinite scroll, where the scrollbar begins sized to the initially-loaded content, then jumps repeatedly as the user scrolls to the end of what's loaded so far. This is as opposed to replacing a finite-but-long list with a big box sized to the height a table would be if all rows had loaded, and using fixed-height rows dynamically loading in sets of rows as the user scrolls, so the scrollbar never jumps (as this question was originally asking about). It's unfortunate there's no clearly established terminology for this distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [virtualRepeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) from Angular Material

It implements dynamic reuse of rows visible in the viewport area, just like ui-scroll

Comment: It may work for a very basic case. But there are some limitations for this component in case you are actually having more directives as list items. [see discussion](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9317)